# String allocation behaving strangely

Tags: string, rust, allocation

This compiles fine (from the rust lang book):

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello");
    s.push_str(", world");
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

This does not:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello").push_str(", world");
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

The strange thing is that the error occurs in the println! statement:

> 3 |     println!("{}", s);   |
> ^ `()` cannot be> formatted with the default formatter

I'm new to this and trying to push the envelope a little bit, so can someone clarify this?

Comment: That's not the actual error, and not the full error message. The actual error is `'()' doesn't implement 'std::fmt::Display'`, which makes sense if you look at the definition of [`push_str()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push_str)

Comment: If you know Python, that's sort of like `print([1, 2, 3].append(4))` printing `None` instead of the expected `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. (The difference is that Rust treats the attempt to print its equivalent of no-return value as a compile-time error.)

Answer (score 3):

`push_str()` does not have a return value, i.e. it returns `()` which cannot be printed. So by appending it `s` gets type empty tuple and not `String` anymore.

Comment: Ok, makes totally sense. Thank you